# Loading PNG files into TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to load custom made png files I generated to train my model. Following the instruction from TensorFlow guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data), I used this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path, WindowPath

train_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'file_name': {0: WindowsPath('hypothesis/temp/81882f4e-0a94-4446-b4ac-7869cf198534.png'), 1: WindowsPath('hypothesis/temp/531162e2-2b4c-4e64-8b3f-1f285b0e1040.png')}, 'label': {0: -0.019687398020669655, 1: 0.0002379227226001479}}
)

file_path_list = [i.read_bytes() for i in train_df['file_name']]

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=file_path_list)

raw_example = next(iter(dataset))
parsed = tf.train.Example.FromString(raw_example.numpy())
```

Running the `raw_example...` line returns this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 43: invalid start byte
```

I generated the PNG files using matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest reading the png files with tensorflow's builtin io methods. The code snippet below will generate a list of files with .png extension and then iterate over them. During each iteration it reads the file and then decodes the png encoded image

```
image_dir = 'hypothesis/temp'
image_root = pathlib.Path(image_dir)
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(image_root/'*.png'))
for f in list_ds:
  image = tf.io.read_file(f)
  image = tf.io.decode_png(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `i.read_bytes()`. That reads the contents of the file, when you just want the file name.

The minimal change would be something like this:

```
file_path_list = [str(i) for i in train_df['file_name']]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=file_path_list)
```

But if you just want a list of file paths, there's no reason to construct a dataframe first:

```
file_path_list = ['foo/bar/1.png', 'foo/bar/2.png']
```

The reason you were getting the error is that TFRecordDataset() expected a list of strings in filenames, so it tried and failed to convert the binary file data to utf-8.

Comment: How can I load the png file using this syntax? trying to load it by iterating on the data set and using `tf.train.Example.FromString` gives me this error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: corrupted record at 0`