# How to load 3D MRI images into deep learning images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, medical-imaging, simpleitk

I am working on prostate cancer classification task using MRI images, in my case, each patient has both ADC and DWI images. I have preprocessed all ADC and DWI images, and labeled them, the label is in name of image file. And then I have splited the dataset into train and test, validation sets on patient level. I need to concatenate both ADC and DWI images and load into the model. How can i do that? How do I load data into the deep learning model? Please help me, thank you in advance.

This is my file structure

```
Train/
Patient1/
ADC/
adc_image_0.png
adc_image2.png
...
DWI/
dwi_image_1.png
dwi_image2.png
...
Patient2/
ADC/
adc_image1.png
adc_image2.png
...
DWI/
dwi_image1.png
dwi_image2.png
...
...
Test/
(Same structure as Train)
Validation/
(Same structure as Train)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the images with `tensorflow` directly as vectors, as in example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62803250/13339621).

As you said, you need to concatenate the images. For this, try to [expand the dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65305663/13339621) of each vector for as many images you need to add. Careful, all the images should have the same dimensions (`height x width`) before being concatenated so maybe you'll need to resize them.

Assuming an image has dimensions (`height x width x 3`) with 3 corresponding to RGB pixels; finally, an input to the neural net can be a vector with dimensions (`n_images x height x width x 3`).